# Error message: invalid multibyte char (UTF-8) in "vagrant up" while Installing Open edX Platform

Tags: utf-8, vagrant, openedx

During "vagrant up", I am getting the following error message during installation of devstack and fullstack of edX platform. 
My dev envirnments are Windows7 and powershell, the latest versions of Virtual Box and Vagrant.

```
PS C:\Users\user\devstack> vagrant up
There is a syntax error in the following Vagrantfile. 
The syntax error message is reproduced below for convenience:

C:/Users/user/devstack/Vagrantfile:1: invalid multibyte char (UTF-8)
```

By the way, I was able to fix the problem by open and save Vagrantfile in UTF-8 format using a text editor (i.e. notepad or sublime text). Is there a better way to fix the problem? I wonder whether it is something to do with my dev environment problem or Cypress release problem.

I would appreciate if you guide me anything that I may try to fix this error.

(a debtor)<><

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vagrantfile is a ruby file so if you have special character so you can specify the specific encoding you're using in the first lines of the script.

so as first lines, you will have something like

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
# encoding: UTF-8
```

Comment: Thank you. I still need to open and save it in encoding UTF-8, right?

Comment: well, it should be fine, the system would recognize the UTF-8 characters with this option